# $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R^n}) \subset \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R^n})$?

Tags: distribution-theory

Can I have pls the proof of why is the space of distribution with compact support $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R^d})$ subset in the set of tempered distribution $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R^n})$?

Comment: $\epsilon'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of linear functionals from $\epsilon(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @LeoHö I meant what I called (space of dist. with cpt support) what is its symbol!

Comment: Also, could you give a definition of the space $\epsilon(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @LeoHö I suspect $\epsilon=C^\infty$; that would make $\epsilon'$ the space of distributions with compact support.

Comment: Start by writing down carefully exactly what it means for a linear functional on $\epsilon$ to be bounded.

Comment: The space of compactly supported distributions is normally denoted by $\mathcal{E}',$ not $\epsilon'$. I changed your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that your $\mathcal E$ is $C^\infty$. Say $\mathcal S$ is the Schwarz space. Define $i:\mathcal S\to\mathcal E$ by $if=f$.

Show $i$ is bounded.

Calculate $i^*:\mathcal  E'\to\mathcal S'$.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of $\mathcal{S}$ we have $\mathcal{S} \subset C^\infty = \mathcal{E}$.

Next, if $\varphi_k \to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}$ then by definition of convergence in $\mathcal{S}$, for every multi-index $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\sup |x^\alpha \partial^\beta \varphi_k|\to 0.$ Especially, taking $\alpha=(0,\ldots,0),$ one has $\sup |\partial^\beta\varphi_k|\to 0$ for all multi-index $\beta$, which means that $\varphi_k\to 0$ in $\mathcal{E}.$ Thus, if $\varphi_k \to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}$ then $\varphi_k\to 0$ in $\mathcal{E}.$

Take $u\in\mathcal{E}'$ and $\varphi_k\to0$ in $\mathcal{S}$. Since $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{E}=C^\infty,$ the pairing $\langle u, \varphi_k \rangle$ is defined. And since $\varphi_k\to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}$ implies that $\varphi_k\to 0$ in $\mathcal{E}$ we have $\langle u, \varphi_k \rangle \to 0$. Thus, $u$ is continuous also over $\mathcal{S}$. This shows that $\mathcal{E}' \subset \mathcal{S}'.$

Comment: Indeed. But you also need to show density so you have injection at the level of transpose maps between duals.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam. I didn't understand the reason for showing density. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You have an inclusion map $J:S\rightarrow E$, This gives a transpose map $J^t:E'\rightarrow S'$, $u\mapsto u\circ J$. Your argument shows $J^t$ is well defined, continuous and of course linear. But you want to interpret this as an inclusion $E'\subset S'$, so this needs $J^t$ to be injective. Now $u$ in the kernel means it vanishes on $S$ and you want to deduce vanishing on all of $E$. This is a consequence of density of $S$ in $E$. Sorry I didn't put mathcal everywhere.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam. Thanks. Now I understand.